# Increasing Year count every January

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks similar to this:

[image]

I know the starting year of the first obs (1963). The obs are in the exact chronological order.  So the next instance of "Jan" (obs 13) indicates that the year is 1964.  Is there a way to create a column "Year" that has increases the current year every time that the next occurrence of "Jan " happens?

In the pic, it would be "1964" and then when "Jan" happens again, 1965 and so on....

There is an answer to a similar problem that was suggested but it doesn't quite do it and here it is:

```
## Make data easily reproducible
df <- data.frame(day=c(24, 21, 20, 10, 20, 20, 10, 15),
             month = c("Jun", "Mar", "Jan", "Dec", "Jun", "Jan", "Dec", "Dec"))

## Convert each month-day combo to its corresponding "julian date"
datestring <- paste("1963", match(df[[2]], month.abb), df[[1]], sep = "-")
date <- strptime(datestring, format = "%Y-%m-%d") 
julian <- as.integer(strftime(date, format = "%j"))

## Transitions between years occur wherever julian date increases between
## two observations
df$year <- 1963 - cumsum(diff(c(julian[2], julian))>0)
```

But this won't do it: Because the last two observations have the same month ("Dec" and then another "Dec") the count for year increases:

[image]

The last observation should still read "1960" NOT "1959".

Comment: In the "R fill in missing year by order" years are numbered in DECREASING order.  Anyway to do this in INCREASING Order?  Thanks

Comment: then instead of subtracting `df$year <- 2014 - cumsum(...)`, do addition: `df$year <- 20xx + cumsum(...)`

Comment: @scmi Replacing subtraction by addition is not sufficient. You need also to change the comparison operator from `>` to `<`.

Comment: @Use: yeah, sure, it's pretty obvious how to invert the expression. My point was this is a near-duplicate question and hence should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has requested to complete the years in *ascending* order starting in 1963.

The approach below works without date conversion and dummy dates and can be amended to work with fiscal years ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48381054/3817004)).

```
df$year <- 1963 + cumsum(c(0L, diff(100L*as.integer(
  factor(df$month, levels = month.abb)) + df$day) < 0))
df
```

> ```
>   day month year
> 1  24   Jun 1963
> 2  21   Mar 1964
> 3  20   Jan 1965
> 4  10   Dec 1965
> 5  20   Jun 1966
> 6  20   Jan 1967
> 7  10   Dec 1967
> 8  15   Dec 1967
> ```

Note that there is a  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25632652/3817004) which seems to be similar but was asking to complete years in *descending* order. The [solution there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48381054/3817004) needs to be changed in two places to work here.